# How do I format a disk partition from the command line on OS X?

Tags: macos, command-line, partition, disk-format

How do I format a disk partition from the command line on Mac OS X?

In case someone wonders why: because for some people Disk Utility fails.

Comment: Another reason you might want to do this: you don't have GUI access to the box.

Comment: ...or remote desktop is flaky over VPN! Or you want 300G partitions on a 6TB disk. I'm getting annoyed by the constant time machine popups that I'm not interested in, and it won't alllow me to partition all in one go saying the previous volume needs to be mounted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`diskutil list`

In my case I wanted to format the parition as NTFS for installing Windows 7 on it. The last parameter is the partition 4 on first disk.

`diskutil eraseVolume "Tuxera NTFS" my-ntfs disk0s4`

Answer (score 12):

For those of you looking to format an entire disk and remove all partitions here is the command:

```
diskutil eraseDisk free itsfree /dev/disk6
```

Even though I am formatting with free space-- I still had to give it a name for the command to work, in this case **itsfree**.

**To list your disks**

```
diskutil list
```

**To securely erase - Needs to have a mounted volume**

diskutil secureerase freespace 0 /dev/disk6s2

**To list available filesystems**

```
diskutil listFilesystems
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Multipe partitions

```
sudo diskutil partitionDisk /dev/disk9 11 GPT \
    JHFS+ one 298.1G \
    JHFS+ two 298.1G \
    JHFS+ three 298.1G \
    JHFS+ four 298.1G \
    JHFS+ five 298.1G \
    JHFS+ six 298.1G \
    JHFS+ seven 298.1G \
    JHFS+ eight 298.1G \
    JHFS+ nine 298.1G \
    JHFS+ ten 298.1G \
    JHFS+ eleven R
```