# How do I format a partition with FAT32?

Tags: terminal, disk-format

The command `diskutil eraseDisk` is not what I want because that wipes the entire disk. I have a partition already allocated and it is blank. All I need to do is format it with VFAT/FAT32. How can this be done from Terminal? It must the same effect as using `mkfs.vfat` on Linux.

Comment: See [this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/249519/205408).

Answer (score 5):

The command is `newfs_msdos`.

Also for HFS+, the command is `newfs_hfs`.

Use `man newfs_msdos` or `man newfs_hfs` for more information.

Generally, you would use `diskutil list` to get the slice (identifier).

Next you use `diskutil unmount identifier`, followed by the format command.

Finally, use `diskutil mount identifier`.

For example.

```
diskutil list
diskutil unmount /dev/disk0s4
newfs_msdos -F 32 -v BOOTCAMP /dev/disk0s4
diskutil mount /dev/disk0s4
```

### Note: Using `diskutil` to format a partition (slice) can have the side effect of altering the type of partitioning a drive is using.

For example, the command

```
diskutil eraseVolume fat32 BOOTCAMP /dev/disk0s4
```

can result in changing a GPT partitioned disk into a hybrid GPT/MBR partitioned disk.

Comment: I will include your eraseVolume addendum in my answer, so it will not mess your answer :-)!

Answer (score 4):

Enter `diskutil list` to get the disk identifier/partition. Then enter:

```
diskutil eraseVolume FAT32 DATA diskXsY #replace diskXsY by the proper disk identifier
```

*DATA* will be the name of the volume. The name has to be capitalized using `diskutil ...`.

---

**The `diskutil eraseVolume ...` command will change the pMBR of the GUID partition table to a hybrid MBR and probably renders an existing OS X system volume on the same drive unbootable.**